# jq - iterate through dictionaries

Tags: json, bash, iteration, jq

My json knowledge is shaky, so pardon me if I use the wrong terminology.

I have `input.txt` which can be simplified down to this:

```
[
  {
    "foo1": "bar1",
    "baz1": "fizz1"
  },
  {
    "foo2": "bar2",
    "baz2": "fizz2"
  }
]
```

I want to iterate through each object via a loop, so I'm essentially hoping to tackle just the 1's first, then loop through the 2's, etc.

I thought it was something like:

```
jq 'keys[]' input.json | while read key ; do
    echo "loop --$(jq "[$key]" input.json)"
done
```

but that's giving me

```
loop 0
loop 1
```

where I would expect to see (spacing here is optional, not sure how jq would parse it):

```
loop { "foo1": "bar1", "baz1": "fizz1" }
loop { "foo2": "bar2", "baz2": "fizz2" }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Generally, if you want to do something to each object, try to do it *in* the `jq` filter. Otherwise, you should probably process the JSON using a language that can decode the JSON into a proper data structure, rather than using the shell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to use `bash`, you can do this in `jq` itself:

```
jq -r 'keys[] as $k | "loop: \(.[$k])"' file.json
```

```
loop: {"foo1":"bar1","baz1":"fizz1"}
loop: {"foo2":"bar2","baz2":"fizz2"}
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using the `-c` option:

```
$ jq -c '.[]' file | sed 's/^/loop /'
```

```
loop {"foo1":"bar1","baz1":"fizz1"}
loop {"foo2":"bar2","baz2":"fizz2"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming **response** is a variable containing your data :

```
echo "$response" | jq --raw-output '.[] | "loop " + tostring'
loop {"foo1":"bar1","baz1":"fizz1"}
loop {"foo2":"bar2","baz2":"fizz2"}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: this was the only answer that actually worked for me. repsone being "{key:val} {key:val} {key:val}"